# Redirect # character to homepage using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect e.g `https://example.com/#` to `https://example.com/`. How can I do it using .htaccess?

Thanks!

Comment: You can’t, since the hash portion of the URL is not even send to the server to begin with. You’ll need to do this client-side.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, can you provide an example on how to achieve it client-side?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because the fragment part of the url (#some-element) is not sent to the server. So the server doesn't know about whether you are accessing `example.com/#` or `example.com`.